# WinRT XAML ItemsControl Children binding

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, itemscontrol

I have the following XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

How do I set the `DataContext` of `MyControl` to a single item of the `ItemsControl`?

**NOTE:** `ItemsControl` is embedded in a `UserControl`. The `UserControl` has it's `DataContext` property set in the place where it's being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Just changed {Binding DataContext} to {Binding}**